# JS unserializing a PHP serialized array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, serialization

I have an php made array:

```
<?php information = array (
    'name' => 'John',
    'surname' => 'Doe'
); ?>
```

I serialize this array with php and put it into input's value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="information" name="information" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($hidden_information)); ?>" />
```

Now JS part. I get this input's value:

```
var information = $('input#information').val();
```

And the question part: how can I now unserialize with JS this PHP serialized array? I want to unserialize 'information' variable.
When it will be unserialized, I want to alert name and surname from array.

Or probably, is there any possible way to get this name and surname without unserializing the array?

Comment: You should only serialize if you are comunicating with PHP, if you want to have the name and surname of the person, just create 2 input fields with this info, if this is what you want I can create you an answer.

Comment: It will also communicate with PHP later for some other necessities. That's why I need to serialize it.

Comment: Use a format that both understand like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to transform the array to JSON format, it will be easier for JS to understand, so do this in your html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="information" name="information" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($hidden_information)); ?>" //This will comunicate with PHP
<input type="hidden" id="js_information" name="js_information" value="<?php echo json_encode($hidden_information); ?>" />
```

The **information** input will be use to comunicate with PHP and **js_information** for comunicating with JS. Then you can get that info in JS using:

```
var information = JSON.parse($('#js_information').val());
```

*Note: You'll need to have PHP 5.2 or superior, also there's no need to put **input** in the jQuery selector because you have the ID specified*
`

Comment: You still need to encode HTML’s special characters.